# How to deploy Titanium Projects to Android customers?

Tags: android, deployment, titanium

I want to deliver a finished and working Titanium App to Android customers. But I can't find any documentation about how to produce something like a jar-file that I can create to directly install it on Android devices without the Android market or the Titanium IDE at hand (I can't expect my users to install Titanium IDE first, right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a build for device in titanium studio, titanium studio creates an `apk` file for you.

You can find this at `Titanium Workspace/Your Project/Build/Android/bin/app.apk`. This is the app file you want.

This file can be e-mailed to your customers, and if the android phone is set to accept apps from 3rd party locations, they can install it through this e-mail.

Comment: To take this further, you can add it to the Android Market, Amazon Market, B&N Market, Samsung Market, etc.

Comment: For that, you'll need to build for the market, and this will generate an APK file on a different location :)

Answer (score 1):

See the Appcelerator Wiki:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Deploying+to+Android+devices
and
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Distributing+Android+apps